# Basics of I18n For Yii Framework

Tags: php, internationalization, yii

[Yii's I18n topic](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n) isn't enough for me.

My source lang is Turkish , target lang is English (for example)

My test controller's index action :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        Yii::app()->language='en';
        $this->render("index");
    }
```

This is my view file's content :

```
echo Yii::t('test', 'Deneme');
```

And lastly, this is my *protected/messages/en/test.php* file's content:

```
return array(
    'Deneme' => 'Example',
);
```

Everything OK, it's returning **Example** . But as you can see, i'm setting language manually on my **index action**. How can i do it automatically ? Must i add **Yii::app()->language='en';** to all actions? How you are using l18n on your projects ?

Note : I'm Yii and l18n noob, so please describe step by step .

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the target language in `CWebApplication:beginRequest()`

in `protected/config/main.php`, add:

```
'onBeginRequest' => array('MyApp', 'beginRequest')
```

In protected/components, create a file `MyApp.php`, and add this class:

```
class MyApp {
  public static function beginRequest(CEvent $event) {
    //set your language, theme, etc here
  }
}
```

Remember to declare `beginRequest()` as `static`, or you will encounter errors like this:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/794

Answer (score 3):

it's fairly simple. You do all language translations as you said. Then, in the parent controller, in the init method, yo can check the desired language and set the current language. That way, you don't have to do that in every action, just once.

Answer (score 1):

in the Yii's tutorials there is an article that has explained it very good.
in this way you have 3 file: one, your language selector, one, language selector's widget and one is an behavior for handling your language selector file.
read here and use it...
  [Manage (Target) Language in Multilingual Applications + A Language Selector Widget (i18n)](http://shgn.ir/go_to.php?url=www.yiiframework.com/wiki/293/manage-target-language-in-multilingual-applications-a-language-selector-widget-i18n/)